# Optimal point pairs for estimating the distance function in a metric space

Tags: experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, metric, optimal

I’m looking for the name of the methods or subfield that deals with problems like this:

Assume that we have $n \times m$ points over a regular grid.They are embedded into a metric space. We can get the distance between any two points ($d(P_i, P_j)$) but we do not know how the distance is calculated, imagine it as being a black box function.

The goal is to estimate the unknown distance function ($d(.,.)$). What are the optimal point pairs for estimating the distance functions if we can evaluate the black box distance function at $k$ point pairs.
Optimal in a sense that they are the most informative about the distance function (in order to make an accurate approximation of it).

For example, for $k = 2$ and not coinciding points, $[d(A, B), d(C, D)]$ is more informative than $[d(A, B), d(A, B)]$, however $[d(A, B), d(B, D)]$ might be even more informative than the first two pairs (certainly in respect of the $d(A, C)$ distance).

What are the approaches for solving these types of problems? What keywords should I search for?

I was looking into the design of experiments and combinatorial design but haven’t found anything yet. Any ideas and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

### Update

To give more context: the black box function is expert assessment of the distance between two objects (images depicting physical phenomena) and I would like to have a mathematical approximation of the expert assessment to be able to replace them with something cheaper and faster. I would like to give a set of pairs to the experts that would extract the most information from them in order to make an approximate function. I cannot present the pairs adaptively, i.e. adjusting the to be assessed pairs based on their answers (or to be more precise, I would like to avoid this as it would require additional effort to set the supporting infrastructure up).

Comment: Is the grid important? For instance, can you assume that (1,1) is closer to (1,2) than to (1,3)?

Comment: @MattF. The grid is not important. I just wanted to make it simpler, rather than having the possibility to put the points anywhere. "can you assume that (1,1) is closer to (1,2) than to (1,3)?" in the general case I cannot but I would be interested in an approach if I could assume that.

Comment: You *must* assume not only that this embedding is continuous, but also that you have some bounds for how much it distorts the metric.  Otherwise there is nothing to distinguish any pair of points from any other.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment! The continuity requirement should be met, also the distortion can be assumed to be bounded given the physical nature of the problem. Could you point me to the direction of reading materials on related problems or methods?

Comment: I am unaware of any literature (which is my limitation, not a statement about the literature!)  The first places I would look for some would be in papers on *graph embedding* and, for statistical approaches, on *multidimensional scaling* (MDS) and dimensionality reduction generally.